# Expressions in c return 1 for true

Tags: c

In c programming ,all non zero numbers can be used in conditional expressions to return true. In that aspect why do expressions which evaluate to true return 1 ,not any other non zero value?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d",6==6);
}
```

output: 1

Comment: same reason as why C require main function requires main function to return 0 on normal exit: convention.

Comment: They don't necessarily. The `is....()` family returns non-0.

Comment: @user3528438 but that is `0` in your case meaning "true". For abnormal exit `main` can return any non-0 value that can be trapped by the caller, for example a batch file can use `errorlevel`.

Comment: There's no conditional expression in this code. Your `==` expression has type `int`, and it has well-defined semantics. In particular, it does *not* "evaluate to true". That's just something you made up.

Answer (score 3):

This is defined in the C standard:

> **6.5.13 Logical AND operator**
>
> The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0.  The result has type int.

Similar for the other logical operators.

It makes a lot of sense to have a deterministic value for these cases, and the lowest positive non-zero value is a good candidate for that.

Answer (score 3):

[C11 draft](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf&pli=1)

**6.5.9 Equality operators**
3

> The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the
>   relational operators except for their lower precedence.108) Each of
>   the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it
>   is false. The result has type int. For any pair of operands, exactly
>   one of the relations is true.

Answer (score 0):

Because as you said, evaluating the both sides of that kind of expressions, the result could be true or false, that is a boolean value. By definition and convetion, in C standard, boolean values are represented with a 1 for true and 0 for false.

Comment: I think it's more by definition. `(a==a)` evaluates to `1`.

Comment: 1 is not the only value that represent `true`, any value that is not 0 is `true`.